# Как решить ошибку Can't resolve 'grpc' на React?

Tags: reactjs, npm, grpc, rpc

Уже всё перепробовал, весь интернет перешерстил, ничего не помогает

Делаю gRPC клиента на React. Возникает ошибка:

```
ERROR in ./src/pg/m_grpc_pb.js 9:13-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'grpc' in 'X'
```

И оно ничем не лечится вообще! Пробовал различные npm install, но ничего не помогает

Код `m_grpc_pb.js`

```
// source: X.proto
// GENERATED CODE -- DO NOT EDIT!
/* eslint-disable */
// @ts-nocheck
"use strict";
const grpc = require("grpc");
const X_pb = require("./X_pb.js");
const google_protobuf_wrappers_pb = require("google-protobuf/google/protobuf/wrappers_pb.js");
const google_protobuf_timestamp_pb = require("google-protobuf/google/protobuf/timestamp_pb.js");
const XProtoModels_pb = require("./XProtoModels_pb.js");
```

Comment: Что указано в `/src/pg/m_grpc_pb.js`? Судя по тексту ошибки, смотреть надо на 9ю строку

Comment: // source: X.proto
// GENERATED CODE -- DO NOT EDIT!
/* eslint-disable */
// @ts-nocheck
"use strict";

const grpc = require("grpc");
const X_pb = require("./X_pb.js");
const google_protobuf_wrappers_pb = require("google-protobuf/google/protobuf/wrappers_pb.js");
const google_protobuf_timestamp_pb = require("google-protobuf/google/protobuf/timestamp_pb.js");
const XProtoModels_pb = require("./XProtoModels_pb.js");

Comment: a packege.json?